# Существует ли в OpenMP передача задач от одного потока другому?

Tags: gcc, openmp

Я изучаю работу `OpenMP` (работаю с исходниками `gcc-4.7.4`). Мой вопрос состоит в следующем: предусмотрена ли передача задач между потоками во время работы? То есть, если допустим из двух потоков один простаивает, то часть задач из другого потока переходит к нему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если "задачи" это итерации цикла, то есть опция schedule, задающая распределение задач. Тут надо самому думать, какая именно подходит.
Кроме этого в голову приходит только создание пула задач, из которого тредобезопасно потоки будут выхватывать задачи.